# How does this conclusion follow from Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

In the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308012/for-a-semigroup-tt-t-geq-0-x-0-is-the-only-entire-element-if-ts) it states that for given Banach space $E$, semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ on $E$ with generator $A$, functional $\varphi \in E^*$, $x\in E$, we have that the entire function 
$$F_\varphi(\zeta) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\varphi(A^nx)\zeta^n$$
is identically equal to 0. Until here I completely follow, but then it says that Cauchy's Theorem implies that actually $\varphi(A^nx) = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$. To my knowledge Cauchy's integral theorem is about the integral of a holomorphic function over a contour in a simply connected domain being equal to 0, so to me it seems weird that the assertion follow from this theorem.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: The result follows from the Cauchy formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula?wprov=sfla1) $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$

Comment: Why? What should be $a_n$ and $f$ in my case?

Comment: $a_n=\frac{\phi(A^n x)}{n!}$, $f(\zeta)=F_{\phi}(\zeta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $F_{\varphi}(z)$. We know that $F_{\varphi}(z)=0$, and that $\oint z^n dz=2\pi i \delta_{-1}^n$. From this, we get

$$0=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{\sum \frac{\varphi(A^kx)}{k!}z^k}{z^{n+1}}=\\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum \frac{\varphi(A^kx)}{k!}\oint z^{k-n-1}=\sum \frac{\varphi(A^kx)}{k!}\delta_{-1}^{k-n-1}=\frac{\varphi(A^nx)}{n!}$$

The exchange of $\sum, \oint$ is justified by the uniform convergence inside the radius of convergence of the power series.

Using Cauchy integral formula we can avoid almost all of the calculations, and obtain directly $$0=\frac{\varphi(A^nx)}{n!}$$